# Cloudflare not going to https://example.com but going to www.example.com

Tags: ssl, cloudflare

Cloudflare not going to https://example.com but going to [www.example.com](http://www.example.com)

I'm using Cloudflare SSL and all are configured as it is, but when using https://www.example.com or [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) it correctly going to the site.

But when I'm using https://example.com it doesn't go to the site. http://example.com also not working.

I have used Always use HTTPS on Cloudflare and also have added a site rule as

http://example.com/*  Always Use HTTPS

Comment: Can you provide more information about your cloudflare and server config? Are you trying to redirect one the root to the www subdomain or just want your site to be accessible on both domains? Does your server only listens on www but doesn't listen on the root? Ideally you'd make sure there's a DNS record for the root, then create a page rule to redirect your root to www.

Comment: Can you please post your DNS settings and complete page rules?